# Scroll view with a special effect

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to make a screen with like the video I attach. 
I want to scroll until a part of the screen, then, that part sticks in the top and I can go on scrolling.

[sample video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nwh1r68tioc7owd/VID_20140522_140406943.mp4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Name and Image create customview.

```
yourTable.tableHeaderView = yourCustomView_Name_image;
```

For message,call,contact Create customview with 4 `UIButtons`

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   if(section == 0)//do this if you have multiple section.
      return youroutletforcustomview_message_call_contact;
  return nil;
}
```

Maybe this will help you . :)

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution using hard-coded values for a contrived example:

In your view controller create two properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *stickyHeader;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat stickyHeaderYPos;
```

in `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.stickyHeader = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100.0, 320.0, 100.0)];
self.stickyHeader.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[self.scrollView addSubview:self.stickyHeader];
self.stickyHeaderYPos = self.stickyHeader.frame.origin.y;

// Allow us to scroll to test
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 2000.0);
```

Set the view controller as the `UIScrollView`'s `delegate`, and implement `scrollViewDidScroll`

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > self.stickyHeaderYPos) {
        CGRect frame = self.stickyHeader.frame;
        frame.origin.y = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
        self.stickyHeader.frame = frame;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the thing which should stick to the top a table view section header.